# Calculate value based on neighbouring rows in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pairs of values (see 'mjd' column) in the form of the pandas Dataframe:

```
    cor      est        rms     apr         mjd
0   0.12359  80.53359   0.01639 80.41       57754.0
1   -0.01281 80.21719   0.01642 80.23       57755.0
2   0.03876  80.26876   0.01743 80.23       57755.0
3   0.08924  80.40924   0.01779 80.32       57756.0
4   0.06863  80.38863   0.01686 80.32       57756.0
5   -0.07582 80.01417   0.01748 80.08999    57757.0
6   0.13964  80.22963   0.01773 80.08999    57757.0
7   0.03911  79.01908   0.01809 78.97997    57758.0
```

Now, I want to create a new dataframe with the same columns but calculating mean of the neighbouring sequence of rows 0 and 1; 2 and 3; 4 and 5 etc.

Expected output:

```
    cor     est     rms     apr     mjd
0   0.05539 80.3754 0.01640 80.32   57754.5 
1   0.064   80.339  0.01761 80.275  57755.5
2   -0.0035 80.2014 0.01717 80.2049 57756.5
3   0.08937 79.6243 0.01791 79.5349 57757.5
```

Comment: What is expected output with numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approximately 20 % faster than the `GroupBy` solutions offered by the other answers, you could also use a [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) mean and then select every second element using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.rolling(2).mean().iloc[1::2]
#        cor        est       rms        apr      mjd
#1  0.055390  80.375390  0.016405  80.320000  57754.5
#3  0.064000  80.339000  0.017610  80.275000  57755.5
#5 -0.003595  80.201400  0.017170  80.204995  57756.5
#7  0.089375  79.624355  0.017910  79.534980  57757.5

%timeit df.rolling(2).mean().iloc[1::2]
#1.17 ms ± 74.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit df.groupby(df.index // 2).mean()
#1.47 ms ± 110 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Note this solution does give you a different index than the other answers.
With some additional testing, I found that the `rolling` solution is faster up to approximately 10K rows, after which `GroupBy` is faster:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100000, 5))
%timeit df.rolling(2).mean().iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True)
%timeit df.groupby(df.index // 2).mean()
#25.5 ms ± 1.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
#23.1 ms ± 1.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: small advice, try test it in large data (maybe same timings, maybe not)

Comment: I added the test results of larger data sets

Comment: Yes I agree!  For my dataset with approximatelly 1500 rows, rolling method is faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can groupby using `df.index // 2`:

```
In [11]: df.index // 2
Out[11]: Int64Index([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], dtype='int64')

In [12]: df.groupby(df.index // 2).mean()
Out[12]:
        cor        est       rms        apr      mjd
0  0.055390  80.375390  0.016405  80.320000  57754.5
1  0.064000  80.339000  0.017610  80.275000  57755.5
2 -0.003595  80.201400  0.017170  80.204995  57756.5
3  0.089375  79.624355  0.017910  79.534980  57757.5
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.rolling(2).mean()[1::2]`

Explaination:

`rolling(2)` will calculate `mean()` for every two consecutive rows. First row of the resulting dataframe will show `Nan` because there is no previous value to calculate mean. The next row will show a mean over 1st adn second rows of the original dataframe etc. Now, if you want to reduce the dataframe in half, calculating mean for non-interlapping sequences(rows 0 and 1; 2 and 3; 4 and 5 etc), then use `[1::2]` indexer to chose only every second row.